# Why does scrolling with the mouse wheel in a custom flash scrollbar work only after clicking on swf once?

Tags: actionscript-3

Why does scrolling with the mouse wheel in a custom flash scrollbar work only after clicking on swf once? Is there a way to be able to scroll in swf without clicking on it first?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The browser is in control of mouse/keyboard events - the flash container can only gain control of them if it is in focus.

It can only get in focus when clicked on / tabbed into.